# NSInteger Property is not increasing

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm beginner programmer in Swift. I'm creating an app where you just click one button and your amount of money is increasing.

The amount of money is currently a core data entity. I've got a problem, because my amount of money is increasing only to value 1. When it's equal to 1 and i tap the button its not increasing.

My ViewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ClickerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var moneyStatusLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Money")

        let results = try? context.executeFetchRequest(request)

    }

    @IBAction func moneyClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let money = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Money", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Money

        money.amount += 1
        print(money.amount)
        moneyStatusLabel.text = String(money.amount)
    }


}
```

My Core Data Files

NSManagedSubclass

Money+CoreDataProperties

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Money {

    @NSManaged var amount: NSInteger

}
```

Money

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Money: NSManagedObject {


}
```

Data Model:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwfUY.png

Comment: Each call to insertNewObjectForEntityForName() creates a *new* object. You have to *fetch* an existing object in order to modify its properties.

Comment: @MartinR is correct. It looks like you're creating a new object. You also need to call money.save() to save the changes.

Comment: ok, thank you i will check it and let you know if its correct